# When traveling abroad, are you "oversea" or "overseas"?

Tags: grammatical-number

I live in Singapore and I will be travelling to Jakarta.

Should I say "*I will be oversea next week.*" or "*I will be overseas next week.*"?

Looking at [Google Maps](http://maps.google.com/maps?q=singapore+to+jakarta), it looks like there are two seas between Singapore and Jakarta.

Is there any instance where I should use "*oversea*"?

Comment: Just use Singlish *“Next week I go oversea lah”*! No, just joking

Comment: @Benoit, Chinese also say that way.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should use *overseas:* both *oversea* and *overseas* literally mean *across a sea,* but *overseas* is much more common for the abstract meaning of *abroad.* So if you're talking about literal travel across a sea, use *oversea:*

> I work in oversea shipping.

While if you mean generally *abroad,* use *overseas:*

> Is there an extra charge for overseas shipping?
>   **I will be overseas next week.**

Edit: Just to clarify, as @kiamlaluno points out, these words make no distinction about the number of seas that you cross. *Seas* in this sense is not literally the plural of *sea,* but rather the abstract notion of the *waters* of the sea that you cross when you go oversea, as opposed to the *lands* that you cross when you go *overland.*

Comment: In American English, _overseas_ has the same meaning that _oversea_ has in British English; It doesn't make reference to more than one sea.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: it doesn’t necessarily refer to more than one sea in British usage either.  Jon’s answer describes my (British) usage very well.  Here’s another way of describing it: if the example could contrast with *here*, or *in this country/continent*, I’d use *overseas*.  (“Will you be around next week?” “No, I’ll be overseas.”)  If the example could contrast with *overland*, I’d say *oversea*.  (“How are you travelling from Gdansk to Helsinki — overland, or oversea?”)

Comment: +1 Spot on. It is certainly only used in comparison to *overland* to my knowledge, and even then might be split into two words.

Comment: If I live in India and am going abroad to Pakistan, can I use *overseas* as well even though there is no sea nor water between them?

Comment: @afriza: No, *overseas* is only used when you actually must cross the sea, usually when you travel to another continent. It just doesn't matter how many seas, beyond one. If you were travelling from India to Pakistan, you would say *I'm going abroad.*

Comment: The term originated in Britain, which is an island, therefore technically everything is over the sea. In UK English _overseas_ is synonymous with _abroad_ as you can't leave the country without crossing a body of water.

Comment: As a UK speaker, I barely recognise "oversea" as a word. I would say "overseas shipping", and I would write "overland or over sea".

Comment: @Colin, @kiamlaluno: Actually, this is interesting: checking the OED, it seems that until the 50’s or so, *oversea* was indeed commonly used in the UK where AmE or modern BrE would use *overseas*.  (E.g., in the *Times*, 1955: “The congress […] has appointed five rapporteurs on […] the French oversea territories.”)  But, fitting with our experience, all its more recent citations of this sense of *oversea* are from semi-fossilised contexts — eg legal statutes and army committee titles (“Defense and Oversea Policy Committee”, 1990). [cont’d]

Comment: @kiamlaluno, @Colin [cont’d]: And in the entry for *overseas*, it notes that “Use of this word is now more common than *oversea* adv.”  So the sources describing *oversea* as the British equivalent of *overseas* are outdated, but not completely erroneous.

Comment: I checked the BNC (_British National Corpus_), and I discovered that _overseas_ is used in UK too. I agree that what I reported is outdated.

Answer (score 4):

I would go with:

> I will be overseas next week.

Overseas, an adverb, means to go beyond the seas. Even with an 's' at the end, I think it still functions as a singular (*confirmation anyone*?). The number of seas doesn't make a difference, and one sea doesn't mean you have to use *oversea*. See this link for definitions:

http://mw1.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/overseas

However, Merriam Webster also lists *oversea*, mainly British usage, as having the same meaning as overseas. Acoording to them *oversea* was used first, in the 12th century, compared to *overseas*, in 1533. Nowadays, without offence to the Brits, you hardly hear *oversea* used.

The nearest synonym to overseas is abroad.

> I will be abroad next week.

An occasion when you might use over sea (note separation):

> They travelled over sea and land.

which, to my ear, sounds better than:

> They travelled over seas and lands.

The other issue is whether overseas would apply if you were travelling to another country without crossing any sea or seas.

By the way, don't confuse *overseas* with *oversee*, which means to supervise or to watch over.

Comment: Does M-W list when 'oversea' was last used in Britain?  I don't recall ever seeing it, and would have regarded it as erroneous if I had, regardless of what M-W said about its historical usage.

Comment: I agree with your remark. Does *overseas* apply if I travel abroad without crossing any sea nor water?

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: No, M-W doesn't mention its passing, in fact, reading the entry, i get the impression 'oversea' is very much alive and well; it is not referred to as archaic etc. But I think we would all agree that overseas is more commonly used, regardless of which part of the world we came from. And, yes, I did regard oversea as erroneous, too.

Comment: @afriza: from the UK, we tend to regard anything in England, Scotland or Wales as 'not overseas' and anything else as 'overseas'.  One of the merits of being a (smallish) island is that you do go 'overseas' to most other countries.

Comment: @afriza: I really don't know, and I haven't found anything authoritative on this point.

Comment: @afriza: As for your situation, each time you left Singapore, you would be going overseas.Having said that, I don't think many Singaporeans would consider themselves as being overseas if they crossed over to neighbouring Malaysia or the nearby Indonesian islands of Bintan and Batam. Instead they might say, "I'm out of the country." Just wondering whether proximity has anything to do with the usage of overseas.

Comment: @Jonathan, @Sky: see my comment on Jon Purdy’s answer — from the OED, it seems that *oversea* was indeed a common equivalent in UK usage until around the ’50s, but that since then (as we Brits have all been reporting), *overseas* has replaced it in UK usage as well.  So M-W is a little out-of-date.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's just me, but that expression sounds very pompous when applied to relatively short distances, no matter how many seas are in between.

When I lived in UK, I never heard the term *oversea* or *overseas* applied to continental Europe.

Go simple and you won't go wrong, just say "I'll be in Jakarta next week".

Comment: But if we was going to visit several countries, rather than saying, "I'll be in Indonesia, Thailand, New Guinea, and the Solomon Islands", it would be more concise to say simply "I'll be overseas." It's also useful if the countries are unknown, like, "This job may require overseas travel."

Answer (score 1):

It would be *overseas* even if you only cross one sea. Or ocean. That's if you're in America. The Brits say *oversea* (singular), but you never hear that over on this side of the pond.

Edit: My CD version of Webster's cites

> overseas |ˈōvərˈsēz| ( Brit. also oversea)

so I included that mention even though I have never heard the usage in any contet from anyone.

Comment: Are you sure about Brits using *oversea*?  As per my comment on Jon Purdy’s answer, I (UK) have always used *overseas* for the most common meaning, and as far as I’ve noticed, that’s the standard British usage.

Comment: I have never heard the singular 'oversea' used in Britain, and I lived there a long time before migrating.  You can use 'oversee' in appropriate contexts, but that is a wholly different word.

Comment: I can't imagine using 'oversea' myself, as a British speaker.  (Of course, with these things, you sometimes never notice yourself doing it.)

Comment: @PLL: My Webster's gives *oversea* as a British usage, but I included that only because I saw it in the reference. I never hear it in the U.S., and from what I'm hearing no one seems to have heard it over there either.

Comment: (repeating myself a little since the same question has arisen in several threads — see comments to Jon Purdy’s answer for details): from the OED, it seems that *oversea* was indeed a common equivalent in UK usage until around the ’50s, but that since then (as we Brits have been reporting), *overseas* has replaced it in UK usage as well.  So Webster’s is a little out-of-date on this, though historically correct.