# "Overseas" vs. "abroad"

Tags: word-choice, adverbs

I'm a native speaker of Inland Northern American English.  My intuition tells me that the word "abroad" is unremarkable, especially in collocations like "study abroad".

However, I've been correcting English entries on Lang-8 lately, and I noticed that a Canadian English speaker made a correction I wouldn't have.  She changed the following clause:

> she told me that she was going study ***abroad*** next month

to this:

> she told me that she was going to study ***overseas*** next month

Her explanation was the following:

> Hardly anyone ever says “abroad” in real life, it’s a bit of an awkward word. We say overseas, in another country, outside the country, etc.

This is quite a different impression than I get when I see the word "abroad".  That said, I know I can't always trust my intuition on matters of usage.

Is she correct?

Comment: In Great Britain, of course, *overseas* is a synonym of *abroad*.  But that isn't actually true in either the US or Canada.  Only a pedant would notice the point, but if you correct somebody else you really should not leave yourself open to pedantry.

Comment: @TimLymington Thank you for pointing that out.  I'm afraid I left out some context!  The person she was correcting lives in Japan.

Comment: @Luke Northern Ireland is, from the perspective of Britain, none of those things.  Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/10858/2085

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'd be interested if your correspondent in Canada would say that a period of study in the United States was overseas or abroad.

Google Ngrams shows that *study abroad* is far more common, even when including "overseas study" in the comparison:

[image: Ngram: study abroad/study overseas/overseas study]

Ngrams are a blunt instrument, but the difference is so marked here that your intuition is undoubtedly correct.

Comment: From Ngrams, it certainly seems that both the U.S. and the U.K. use *abroad* more than *overseas*. Possibly Canada is a different case, since there *overseas* would mean anywhere but the U.S., which might be a useful distinction.

Comment: On the other hand, perhaps it was simply a misguided politically-correct objection to "studying a [broad](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/broad)" which made the word "awkward".

Comment: @PeterShor - does Mexico not exist?

Comment: @alcas And what about Guatemala, Costa Rica and Argentina?

Answer (score 5):

Your critic is being far too prescriptive. The word *abroad* is used more often than *overseas* and has been for centuries. Since the question is one of relative frequency, we can go to Google's NGram viewer [for the answer](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=overseas%2Cabroad&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=).

[image]

It shows that for the past 60 years *abroad* has been top dog, and despite a narrowing in the latter part of the former century and the early part of this century the gap is widening again in its favor.

Even if the numbers were reversed you would still be entitled to use *abroad* wherever you saw fit, immune to the censure of schoolmarmish critics who think language may only be used in ways they prescribe.

Answer (score 4):

As already covered, *Abroad* is used much more often. However I would also add that there is a subtlety in how far the place is that you are talking about. This also doesn't always correlate with whether the destination is actually *over sea* or not.

Clearly anywhere which is a different country can be though of as *abroad*.

However, even though from the UK, France is over a sea, it would not usually be referred to as *overseas*, simply because it is too close. It is however still definitely *abroad*.

On the other hand from France to China, is technically not over a sea, but it would still be refereed to as *overseas*, (although *abroad* also still applies).

As a rule of thumb, I (as a UK English speaker) would only use *overseas* what talking about another continent.

Comment: I suppose that we Brits can refer to the Continent (mainland Europe) as underseas now.

Answer (score 2):

Both Royal Mail in the UK and US Postal Service use "overseas" stamped packaging and envelopes for sending postage to another country.
The mail services of all other European countries including the Russian Post use "abroad" stamped packaging and envelopes.

Answer (score 0):

I think the context of the origin country is significant, in the sense of how big a deal or exotic the destination is vis-a-vis the source country.  overseas indicates big deal/exotic, abroad is more ordinary.

For example US is seen as overseas from India, but possibly abroad from say UK.  The perception could also change over time.  China was overseas for US some time back, but now it is merely abroad.  But Cambodia/Vietnam etc, which are all right next to China could be seen as overseas from US.

So I think use of overseas or abroad reveal perceptions rather than distance or duration.