# The word "abroad" means "to be in another country" or "to be in another city/region" or both?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary

I always thought it literally means "to be in another country" but is it also applicable to someone who's moved to another region within the country?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! It would help to add some more context to your question. Do you have an example of it being used to refer to the latter case? What does a dictionary say?

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin This user ain't coming back, I reckon. They have already checked off the answer that validated their presupposition.

Comment: Also https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/90792/overseas-vs-abroad as a duplicate.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I believe it can be used for both. According to [www.thefreedictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com), "abroad" means "to or in a foreign country". The Cambridge dictionary agrees, however it also says that its "literary or old use" is to say "Outside or not at home". So that would imply that it can be used for someone who has moved to another region, city, or in any way away from home.

Comment: Yes, _abroad_ used to be used for _out of doors_, but this is a different sense of the word from _in another country_. I don't remember ever having seen it used for _in another district_.

Comment: I don't think any native speaker who  hears _abroad_  will think it can apply to another  city or state. // It's similar in usage  to the word _broadcast_, which is used differently since Marconi and Tesla.